# Use of @ in R programming, or R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr-spin

I've downloaded code from another programmer, and they have the following:

```
#' @param gr                a GRanges of regions/DMRs/whatever
#' @param HMM               a GRanges with ChromHMM annotations (name, itemRgb)
#' @param background        a null distribution (universe) whence gr was chosen
#' @param footprint         compute BP footprints instead of number of overlaps?
#' 
#' @return                  a data.frame with overlap frequency and color code
#'
#' @export
```

I recognize the #' as syntax from knitr spin.  But I don't understand how it's being used here or what the `@` symbol is doing.  Please explain.

Comment: Read [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz) about package documentation and look up the **roxygen2** package.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea that this was for a package, since this was emailed to me as is from a collaborator.  I wouldn't have even thought to look at package documentation.  The info is a bit hard to understand for me at my current level, but I'll keep working through it.  Looking it up online wasn't working because Google didn't understand me putting in the @ sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#'` part is designating that this is part to be woven into proper R documentation through R package `roxygen2`. The `@param` are telling the translator to make these things into elements of the documentation.

Example you posted will create a help file which will ultimately be viewed as

```
functionName(gr, HMM, background, footprint)
```

under Usage section of `?functionName` and description of each argument under section Arguments and so on... See the link @joran provided (and [stackoverflow tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/roxygen2/info)) about all available tags you can use to guide the way this inline documentation is made into a full blown .Rd file.

Comment: So this means my collaborator (who wrote the code) made a custom function with documentation that I would render upon request (ie someone typing in `?functionName` into the console)?  I read through a lot of material about the roxygen2 package and the link provided.  I still don't completely understand, but this is very helpful.
Is this something I should be doing if I ever write a custom function that others might use?

Comment: @GaiusAugustus you need to make a package (making documentation is only part of the process) to make `?functionName` available in R. What your collaborator did is probably currently the best option on how to document your code. If you decide to build a package, a vignette is also a good way to go.